# Is this chicken fully cooked or raw?

Tags: chicken, frying, raw

I can never tell whether this color means the chicken needs another 30 seconds or a minute to finish or if it's properly cooked. I don't want to over-fry the chicken so that it doesn't end up dry.
Is the color in the following image properly cooked or not?
[image: chicken]

Comment: See my answer to this question.  It applies here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/113688/concern-over-whether-roast-chicken-is-safe - I think it is essentially a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Colour is a fairly inaccurate method of determining if a protein is safe to consume. I would recommend getting a thermometer to determine if the chicken has reached a safe internal temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Colour is never going to be consistent when estimating doneness of meat, so the best way to check is to take its temperature using an instant-read thermometer - general advice recommends at least 75C or 165F. Especially with chicken, it's always better to overcook than to undercook as it carries the risk of salmonella. With chicken though, you can be sure that it is cooked when any juices coming out of it are clear and not pink.

Comment: Culinary advice would never say 165 but 150F. I cook to 155F.